# Moving an image Javascript

Tags: javascript

My JS page

```
const catImage=document.querySelector('img')

let catImageLeft=catImage.style.left='0px'

function catwalk() {

    let position= 0
    setInterval(frame,50)

    function frame() {

        position+=10
        catImage.style.left=position+'px'

        if (position==1080) {
            return catwalk()
        } 
    if (position==540) {
            setTimeout(catImage.src='https://media1.tenor.com/images/2de63e950fb254920054f9bd081e8157/tenor.gif',1000)
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, it keeps on moving after replacing the image. And also if i would like the image to start over again, it stutters.

any suggestions.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want, you want the cat walking gif to be visible from `left=0` to `left=540` and the cat dancing gif from `left=540` to `left=1080` and then start again from 0 infinitely ?

Comment: What I want is to make the walking gif from 0 till 520, then the dancing GIF at 540 pause while the gif runs for a couple of seconds. Then continue from 560 with the walking gif till 1080 then start over again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bftj7hpd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```js
const catImage = document.querySelector('img');
const catWalkimg = 'https://i.imgur.com/Akh489w.gif';
const catDancImg = 'https://media2.giphy.com/media/3mXcJgVhPxWZa/giphy.gif';

catwalk();

function catwalk() {
  let position = 0;
  setInterval(function() {

    position = position > 700 ? 0 : position;

    if (position == 350) {
      if (catImage.src != catDancImg) {
        catImage.src = catDancImg;
        setTimeout(() => {
          catImage.src = catWalkimg;
          position += 10;
        }, 2000);

      }

    } else {
      catImage.style.left = position + 'px';
      position += 10;
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
img {width: 160px}
```

```html
<img style="position:absolute;" src="https://i.imgur.com/Akh489w.gif" />
```